# Lock a resource (threads, C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have two threads (first for read and second for write) and one shared resource (for example array). How to guard resource between threads? (block read, while second thread doing write) (Sorry for bad English)

Comment: Here's one way amongst others: [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard.)

Comment: Use a mutex. That's the standard solution.

Comment: I was reading information about mutex. In examples, mutex is blocking resource in one function. But in my case this is different functions. How do this help me?

Comment: @ЛеонтийХачуев you need common mutex for both function. A very dirty solution would be global variable. Better one - some structure, like a class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[std::mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) wrapped in [std::lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) is the easiest way for novice in multithreading.

Something like this:

```
class Resource {
public:
    T Read() { 
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
       // read
    }  
    T Write() {
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
       // write
    }
private:
    std::mutex m_mutex;
};
```

Comment: Thank you! That is if mutex already locked (for example in read), that write will wait (on lock) and then locked resource again?

Comment: @ЛеонтийХачуев yes, exactly.